# Uncaught TypeError: el is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make a function to disable buttons depending on a media query. This function receives a DOM element. For some reason, I got the following error: **Uncaught TypeError: el.forEach is not a function** when I try to resize the window. I try to debug this and seems that the first run works as expected, but then the argument suddenly change of type to an event and that's how I got the error. So, I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <button class="test">Hey</button>
        <button class="test">Hey</button>
        <button class="test">Hey</button>
        <button class="test">Hey</button>
        <button class="test">Hey</button>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const testElements = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
        const handleDisabled = el => {
            if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 992px)').matches) {
                el.forEach((te => {
                    te.setAttribute('disabled', '');
                }));
            } else {
                el.forEach((te => {
                    te.removeAttribute('disabled');
                }));
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('resize', handleDisabled);
        handleDisabled(testElements);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `window.addEventListener('resize', handleDisabled);` -> `window.addEventListener('resize', () => handleDisabled(testElements));` otherwise you receive the event as `el`.

Comment: You could define testElements inside handleDisabled.  That way it would contain the elements that are on the page when the resize happens, instead of the elements that were on the page initially, in case they change.

Comment: That error message does not make sense. It should be complaining about the forEach

Comment: @VLAZ yeah that fixed the error, I could figure it out later. Thanks!